# iOS Cannot move VIEW by pressing on button Object

Tags: ios, view, touchesmoved

I have an issue with VIEW Objects. I want to move the Parent View if touch was on the button A or B and moving. 
But when button is pressed it should work as usual - just (IBAction)ABtnPressed:(id)sender function.

```
 ----------------------
 |                    |
 |  Parent View       |
 |                    |
 |                    |
 |                    |
 |                    |
 |  ________________  |
 | | Another view   | |
 | | ------  ------ | |
 | | | A  |  |  B | | |
 | | ------  ------ | |
 | |________________| |
 |____________________|
```

How I do it:
 

    `- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
        {
            NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
            UITouch *touch = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
            CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];`

```
    if (touch.view == AnotherView) // It's work properly
    {
          ParentView.center = CGPointMake(ParentView.center.x, touchLocation.y);
    }   

    if (touch.view == AButton) // It's **NOT** work properly
    {
          ParentView.center = CGPointMake(ParentView.center.x, touchLocation.y);
    }
```

Please help me, how I can solve this issue. I just began develop for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Because UIButton has its own touch event, it won't listen to normal touch delegates, You will have to use UIGestureRecognisers, add on both buttons and view like normal selector

Good luck

Comment: I sent an answer to your message.